# How to make a window non-capturable by screenshots?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm trying to make a magnifier app in C# using WPF. Sadly, I can't get it to work, since it records itself. How to capture a screen, **without** capturing my main window?

Comment: Your application record itself or is there some another application that captures the screen?

Comment: Naive approach is to hide your window before taking screenshot of desktop (which you probably doing now).

Comment: It records itself.

Hiding it doesn't work.